# Installation Guide for TileStache on Debian

Tags: debian, leaflet, postgis, tilestache

I am looking for a straight-forward guide to installing and setting up Tilestache.  I am relatively new to the world of Linux and Javascript, so be gentle.

**Background:**

I have installed Apache and Postgres 9.3/Postgis 2.1 on a Debian Wheezy os.  We use Apache to host our utility's website.

I have created a test map using Leaflet at www.jwwu.com/DesktopMap.html.  Right now, it currently just pulls a geojson file from our server using the Ajax-Leaflet plugin.

The loading speed for the geojsons isn't an issue on a desktop, but was abysmal on our tablets.

I would like to use Tilestache to serve vector tiles from our Postgis database, and then integrate the tiles into a Leaflet map.

I found one or two guides online for installing Tilestache, but they didn't really fit my situation.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For a basic TileStache setup I recommend [this guide for Ubuntu](http://proyectosbeta.net/2015/05/tilestache-en-ubuntu-14-10-desktop/) easily adaptable to Debian.

Once you have TileStache working you should follow the info about PostgreSQL/PostGIS [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/tomay/8657441).

Comment: That guide is a tad old now. I have created a new one. https://gist.github.com/gabefair/49a5379511bfb65a25ab2c5e6b1c8816